# remove numbers from a string haskell

Tags: haskell

Let be a string alphanumeric and I want to split it when he founds a number.

```
remove xs = [ x | x <- xs, not (x `elem` ",.?!-:;\"\'0123456789")]
```

I started by those numbers and somne punctuation but I how can I split the string, so I give the string `"I go 25abc tomorrow 100!"->["I","go","abc","tomorrow"]` !

Comment: There is `Data.List.Split` package containing `splitOn` function. Unfortunately it is not standard (hence I don't provide it as an answer), but might be good enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
> import Data.List.Split
> split (dropDelims . dropBlanks $ oneOf " 0123456789") "I go 25abc tomorrow 100!"
["I","go","abc","tomorrow","!"]
```

with `words` a two step approach will work

```
> words $ map (\x -> if x `elem` ['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z'] then x else ' ') "I go 25abc tomorrow 100!"
["I","go","abc","tomorrow"]
```

here I changed the definition of filter to only alpha chars, if not matches your needs you can reverse the if condition by defining the filtered out chars.

By importing `Data.Char(isAlpha)` you can change

```
x `elem` ['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']
```

to `isAlpha x`

Comment: If one has the `Split` package, he can use `splitOn`.

Comment: Even I have imported Data.List.Split it's not working...But If I want to made a function like : words::String-> [String] how can I define for any string.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a recursive function like this:

```
import Data.Char

split :: String -> [String]
split [] = []
split s =
  let -- Remove non alphabetic characters from front of list
      s' = dropWhile (not . isAlpha) s
      -- Split the list at the point where the first non-alphabetic
      -- character appears
      (xs,ys) = span isAlpha s'
      -- Recursively call split on the second list, while prepending 
      -- the first list.
  in  xs:(split ys)
```

Here is what happens with your test string through the recursive calls:

```
s  = "I go 25abc tomorrow 100!"
s' = "I go 25abc tomorrow 100!"
xs = "I"
ys = " go 25abc tomorrow 100!"

s  = " go 25abc tomorrow 100!"
s' = "go 25abc tomorrow 100!"
xs = "go"
ys = " 25abc tomorrow 100!"

s  = " 25abc tomorrow 100!"
s' = "abc tomorrow 100!"
xs = "abc"
ys = " tomorrow 100!"

s  = " tomorrow 100!"
s' = "tomorrow 100!"
xs = "tomorrow"
ys = " 100!"

s  = " 100!"
s' = ""
xs = ""
ys = ""
```

Note that this will split the word `"abc4def"` into `["abc", "def"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Below line of code will split the string whenever it finds number

String[] strArr= str.split("[0-9]");

Comment: That's not Haskell?

Comment: Need to write a parser first :)

Comment: also it does not produce the list as in the given example

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it.

```
splitWithoutNumbers :: String -> [String]
splitWithoutNumbers = map removeNumbers.words
                      where 
                      removeNumbers ""     = ""
                      removeNumbers (s:ss) | isNumber s = removeNumbers ss
                                           | otherwise  = s : removeNumbers ss

*Main> splitWithoutNumbers "I go 25abc tomorrow 100!"
["I","go","abc","tomorrow","!"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
remove = words . filter (liftM2 (||) isAlpha isSpace)
```